# Linq distinct rows based on field within the result

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql

I am trying to filter my results below to only show distinct rows based on the MacAddress field being returned within the select. This works when just returning single values but not on the objects. Any ideas?

```
 // Get all records which have not been imported yet?
        var query = (from s in db.Stagings
            join t in db.Printers on s.MacAddress equals t.MacAddress into tj
            from t in tj.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where t == null
            select new { s.MacAddress,s.PrinterName,s.HostName,s.IPAddress,s.ReportDate}).Distinct();
```

Is it possible to further filter without doing a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this work?

```
var query = (from s in db.Stagings
                join t in db.Printers on s.MacAddress equals t.MacAddress into tj
                from t in tj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where t == null
                select new { s.MacAddress,
                            s.PrinterName,
                            s.HostName,
                            s.IPAddress,
                            s.ReportDate
                        }
                ).GroupBy(s => s.MacAddress)
                .Select(s => s.First());
```